# How to test and troubleshoot PHP's cURL?

Tags: php, linux, curl

I have the following script.  On one server, it displays results, and on the other, nothing is displayed.  cURL support is enabled on both servers, and previously, both servers returned results, however, I recently changed some of the networking configuration of the second server.

How can PHP's cURL be tested and troubleshot?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url='http://test.example.com/_.php?'.http_build_query(['guid'=>'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV','username'=>'username', 'password'=>'password','hash_points'=>'hash_points','hash_config'=>'hash_config','mac_address'=>123]);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,50); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50); //timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);   //Will force curl_exec() to return results
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$rsp = curl_exec($ch);
echo($rsp."\n");
//phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: First I'd say tell us _what_ networking configuration details you changed. There is little sense in _guessing_ what may have caused issues. Second take a look into your http servers error log file, assuming this code is executed in a web environment. Third try raising your timeout to a sane value to make sure this is not the simple cause.

Comment: Did you try setting [`CURLOPT_VERBOSE`](http://php.net/curl_setopt)? That should cause cURL to print debugging information to STDERR.

Comment: @arkascha  I changed `cat /etc/network/interfaces` to use static IPs.  I've increased timeout, and looked at `test.example.com` httpd logs, and it is not being accessed.  Maybe wireshark on the problem server to test?

Comment: @helmbert.  Will `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);` cause it to go to syslog?

Comment: @user1032531, IIRC, stderr will be piped into PHP's errorlog. Alternatively, specify `CURLOPT_STDERR` with an open file handle to write debug output into a file of your choice (or simply `STDOUT`).

Comment: @helmbert  No errors are displayed.  Furthermore, the browser instantly is displayed and is not hanging for curl to complete.

Comment: Turned out my name servers were not set up correctly.

Comment: Which should lead to a name resolution error. Which in turn _must_ get logged to the error log file. Most likely you check the wrong file or you switched off error logging (which you should never do).

Comment: @arkascha  Well, that is good news!  The device is a Raspberry Pi, and I typically use Centos.  I am 99% sure I haven't switched off error logging, but maybe I am looking in the wrong file.  Funny, however, that I generated an error independently of that associated with cURL, and that was displayed.

Comment: An error getting displayed is independent from an error getting logged in the error log file. If you want to examine, then you can simply check the host configurations of your http server. A failing name resolution will raise an error, just check that again to be sure: "Could not resolve host: ... Closing connection. "